# Same namespace but different controllers and views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rest, routes

I have a case when I need `localhost:3000/dashboard` to point to different view/controller combinations based on the type of the user. Two main types in my application are `Subscriber` and `Publisher`.

When `Publisher` logs in and goes to `/dashboard` I need to show the Publisher Dashboard.

When `Subscriber` logs in and goes to `/dashboard` I need to show the Subscriber Dashboard.

At this moment Publisher's dashboard is called `Dashboard` and subscriber's dashboard is called `Profile`. Seems to me a little dirty.

The question is. What is the best way to call the right controller, load the right data and render the right template/layout based on a type of a particular user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider something like the following pseudo code to get you started.

Controller:

```
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb

class Dashboard < ApplicationController

def index      
  render, :user_type => current_user.user_type
end
```

View:
  (Use the helper to change what will be displayed).

```
views/dashboards/index.html.erb

# display the content
```

Helper.

```
helpers/dashboard_helper.rb
module DashboardHelper(user_type)
if user_type == 'publisher'
  #set content / variables for publisher
elsif user_type == 'Subscriber'
  #set content / variables for subscriber
else
  set content/variables to default.
end
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! However, the way I wanted to implement it differs from your suggestion, I did followed your suggestion. The code looks like this:
    `def index`
        `@publisher = @subscriber = current_user`
        `render template: "#{current_user.type.underscore.pluralize}/dashboard"`
    `end`